# Problem in load balance enviroment with XPM

Tags: 2013-sp1, experience-manager, session-preview

I have found a problem working with XPM in a load balance environment with two servers. The Update Preview Button is always showing me the alert to update the preview of the Page.

In the SDL documentation I found something related with the machine name in the `cd_storage_config`, so I put a descriptive machine name on the servers, different between them but I have the same problem.

What is the correct configuration for this type of environment? Is there any other configuration missed?

Comment: I have the same problem on 8.5

Comment: Did you try using same machine name on both servers. I had same scenario but with using same machine name it was working fine for me.

Comment: I have the same machine name in the cd_storage_conf on the 6 load balanced servers, yet I see the Update Preview popup multiple times. The updates disappear as soon as I leave the component.